# How to select rows in a table whose row.names match any element from a character vector?

Tags: r

I have a big table (over 20,000 rows) containing a couple of columns saved in a matrix `x`. I also have character vector `z` containing a couple of thousand of the row names used in the big table. How can I extract all the rows from the matrix `x` where the row name matches one of elements in the vector `z`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
x[row.names(x) %in% z, ]
```

Will work if x has a `row.names` attribute, like a dataframe. You used the words data table and array, so I'm not certain of your exact data structure.

Comment: if the "row names" you want to select in `x` are in one of the columns of `x` you can use `x[x$column %in% z, ]` where `column` is the column of `x` that contains the names